# Creating Include Folder and Lib folders in Visual Studio Projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

It looks to be a general approach when i download a lib from the internet, or install a sdk, that they hold a folder having a include and lib / bin folder.

Over the years I created several visual studio projects, c# or vc++ and wonder how people release their libs when doing them. It found it fairly simple to make the libs come out in a lib folder and exes out in a bin folder.

Are there any easy ways to make visual studio know what header files is supposed to be in the include folder and then make it create this when building, or should i manual maintain this folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own macros in `Visual Studio` after a build. Check the [post build event macros box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your project setting. You can also use a script language like `PERL` to handle the build and the post build events. I actually like the second method better as it gives more flexibility.